# How to pass multiple properties down 2 levels of components while keeping their names in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a component that has a child component. A user will set properties in my component, and then those properties can be pass to my child component. I will have a few required properties in my component, and there is also a property that stores the user defined data.

my component

```
<MyComponent onChange={onChange} hasStatus={true} customData={{data1, data2, data3}} />
```

child component

```
const {onChange, hasStatus, customData } = props
...
<ChildComponent onChange={onChange} status={hasStatus} customData={customData} />
```

With this when the data gets to my child component, the customData couldn't be pulled out by their property names anymore like this:

```
const { data1, data2 } = props
```

How do I keep their names on the second level down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data1` and `data2` exist on `props.customData`. To deconstruct, change to:

```
const { data1, data2 } = props.customData
```

or

```
const { customData } = props
```

There's no general issue here, it's the way you've designed it. The data exists initially on the top level, then gets passed down as properties on single object.